# MySQL Error Unknown column in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, mariadb, heidisql

I've tried to join 3 tables: a, b and c.

my current code:

```
SELECT a.a_id, a.variable1, a.variable2 FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON a.a_id = b.a_id
LEFT JOIN c ON c.c_id = b.c_id
WHERE  a.variable1 IN ('1', '4');
```

now I get

> "Unknown column 'a.id' in 'on clause'".

but I'm not sure how I can avoid this error.

I'm a major beginner so please lots of explanation

Comment: _“now i get "Unknown column 'a.id' in 'on clause'".”_ - rather hard to believe, since your statement does not contain `a.id` in any of the ON clauses.

Comment: Is it `a.id` or `a.a_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the cause:

```
LEFT JOIN a ON a.a_id = b.a_id
```

should probably be

```
LEFT JOIN a ON a.a_id = b.b_id
```

and (?)

```
LEFT JOIN c ON c.c_id = b.b_id
```